# After adding baseline while running flyway migration getting the message - Schema version : null and no migration needed

Tags: docker, flyway

I am using Flyway with Docker and oracle to create a new schemas with db objects. I executed flyway migration and baseline it. After that even though I run Flyway clean or removed the database, cleaning the data volume. Then recreated the empty oracle database and call the  flyway migration I am getting the message as below 
"Current version of schema "GLDDBAMST": null
Schema "GLDDBAMST" is up to date. No migration necessary.
Schema version: null"

Please let me know how can I remove the baseline and start the migration again after cleaning the schema.

```
------------------------Full Message---------------
US_C02XJ1EWJGH5:goldnet-flyway rmehta068$ make config-flyway-migrate
docker-compose -f compose/flyway.yml up config_flyway
WARNING: Found orphan containers (oracle) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Starting flyway_config ... done
Attaching to flyway_config
flyway_config             | Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse
flyway_config             | Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521/ORCLPDB1.localdomain (Oracle 12.2)
flyway_config             | Successfully dropped schema "GLDDBAMST" (execution time 00:00.160s)
flyway_config             | Creating schema "GLDDBAMST" ...
flyway_config             | Creating Schema History table: "GLDDBAMST"."flyway_schema_history"
flyway_config             | Current version of schema "GLDDBAMST": null
flyway_config             | Schema "GLDDBAMST" is up to date. No migration necessary.
flyway_config             | Schema version: null
flyway_config             | 
flyway_config             | +----------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------+---------+
flyway_config             | | Category | Version | Description                  | Type   | Installed On        | State   |
flyway_config             | +----------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------+---------+
flyway_config             | |          |         | << Flyway Schema Creation >> | SCHEMA | 2019-02-04 20:31:01 | Success |
flyway_config             | +----------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------+---------+
flyway_config             | 
flyway_config exited with code 0




Collapse 
Message Input
```

Comment: Does your container has access to migration scripts? Seems like it recreates schema from scratch, but maybe there are no scripts to run. What is the contents of `flyway_schema_history` after this migration run? Can you show the contents of your `compose/flyway.yml`?